# Error emails about Invalid host for django app

Tags: django, gunicorn

My django webapp runs properly using gunicorn, proxied through nginx; but I keep getting error emails: [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '112.124.42.80'. You may need to add '112.124.42.80' to ALLOWED_HOSTS. Each time the IP changes, and I suspect this is a security issue.

I've only started to notice this issue a week ago, and the only significant change I've made was to set up using Cloudflare as CDN

```
Report at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '112.124.42.80'. You may need to add '112.124.42.80' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Request Method: HEAD
Request URL: http://112.124.42.80/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Python Executable: /xxx/xxxx/xxxx/.virtualenv/bin/python3.6
Python Version: 3.6.8

META:
HTTP_ACCEPT = 'text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'close'
HTTP_HOST = '112.124.42.80'
HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = '60.191.52.254'
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO = 'http'
HTTP_X_REAL_IP = '60.191.52.254'
PATH_INFO = '/'
QUERY_STRING = ''
RAW_URI = '/'
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_PORT = '49562'
REQUEST_METHOD = 'HEAD'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = '0.0.0.0'
SERVER_PORT = '3030'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.0'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'gunicorn/19.9.0'
gunicorn.socket = <gevent._socket3.socket object, fd=13, family=2, type=2049, proto=0>
wsgi.errors = <gunicorn.http.wsgi.WSGIErrorsWrapper object at 0x7f81a34dccc0>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <gunicorn.http.body.Body object at 0x7f81a34dc9e8>
wsgi.multiprocess = True
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = '(1, 0)'
```

Comment: `import socket` and try adding `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py`.

Comment: What would this resolve please?

Comment: Only the IP addresses or FQDNs mentioned in ALLOWED_HOST are allowed to serve your website. So everytime your IP address changes you need to add it to the ALLOWED_HOST or add FQDN of your machine which I guess should remain same even if IP address changes. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

Comment: `socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())` get s current IP address of your machine, so that you don't need to update `ALLOWED_HOST` again and again

Comment: That's the thing, my IP doesn't change, and the app has been running smoothly but I still get these error messages. I read somewhere that this may be caused by an automated bot targetting my server, but cannot find how to detect or resolve it.

Comment: _the app has been running smoothly but I still get these error messages_ I don't understand.  So the errors don't have any actual effect on the app?

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah, there is no apparent effect on the app. I use public gitlab runners for my CI/CD setup and have been wondering if this could be the cause (the gitlab pipeline always fails). Please what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your web app is usually accessed through a fully qualified domain name.  It sounds like different IP addresses are pointing to your server, and nginx is routing these through to gunicorn, and so to Django.  Django is doing the right thing in blocking them, but it would be better if nginx was not passing them through.  You should change your nginx configuration so it only proxies the addresses you expect.  You might want to look at the `default_server` settings.